# Split XLSX and XLS files into smaller files in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I need to parse XLS/XLSX files using ruby. There are fantastic gems (roo, rubyXL, Spreadsheet, etc) are available for this job, but unfortunately non of these are able to handle files beyond 50K rows (~ 6-8 MB file).

I am thinking of splitting XLS/XLSX files into smaller chunks. Is there a way to split these files and later I can parse smaller ones?

**Update:**
I ended up using different libraries for XLS(spreadsheet) and XLSX(rubyXL), as @YevgeniyAnfilofyev mentioned. The memory foot-print is really high while using rubyXL though.

Comment: Hm, I've parsed files with size up to 500K. What error did you get?

Comment: I mean 50K rows ~ 6-8 MB, let me update my question

Comment: Just successfully created test file by `spreadsheet` gem with 60K rows and 100 columns, size of file is 38.5Mb. So, what error did you get?

Comment: It did not give any error while parsing file, the process thread took 100% CPU for an hour and did not parse a single line. Did you parse XLS and XLSX with spreadsheet gem?

Comment: XLS only, for XLSX used rubyXL

Comment: Yep, I saw that on StackOverflow, but I just want to use one library, and roo supports both, so I am thinking about splitting bigger file. But considering your option, is rubyXL able to handle 50K + rows in XLSX?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26883/discussion-between-gouravtiwari21-and-yevgeniy-anfilofyev)

Comment: I ended up using different libraries for XLS(spreadsheet) and XLSX(rubyXL), as @YevgeniyAnfilofyev mentioned.